# Wrong SHA-1 hash with STM32 Crypto Library

Tags: encryption, cryptography, stm32, sha

With TrueStudio, I'm developing on the STM32f103RB with the STM32 Crypto Library Package 'STM32CubeExpansion_Crypto_V3.1.0'. I would like to use the sha-1 from lib but from some reason I don't get the correct result.

Here is my test...

My input buffer is: `"('1543409074.11', '1702635382a7b4243308035dfecc1e5e31678356bdfa39f92b6409a2')"`

From [SHA1 and other hash functions online generator](http://www.sha1-online.com), result for sha1:  `c6818ce06b79c91cda7cc89f1af243e3d1373c1f`

With the STM32 Crypto Library, I can't seem to generate the correct SHA-1 sum. 
For instance, I call SHA-1 hash function with the following code :

```
  SHA1ctx_stt SHA1ctx_st;            // The SHA1 context
  membuf_stt mb_st;                  // structure that will contain the preallocated buffer
  uint8_t Digest[CRL_SHA1_SIZE];     // Buffer that will contain the SHA-1 digest of the message
  uint8_t preallocated_buffer[4096]; // buffer required for internal allocation of memory

  int32_t status = HASH_SUCCESS;
  int32_t outputSize;

  const char* Message="('1543409074.11', '1702635382a7b4243308035dfecc1e5e31678356bdfa39f92b6409a2')";
  int32_t MessageSize = strlen(Message);


  // Initialize the membuf_st that must be passed to the ECC functions
  mb_st.mSize = sizeof(preallocated_buffer);
  mb_st.mUsed = 0;
  mb_st.pmBuf = preallocated_buffer;

  //Initialize it the SHA-1 Context
  SHA1ctx_st.mFlags = E_HASH_DEFAULT;

  // 20 byte of output
  SHA1ctx_st.mTagSize = CRL_SHA1_SIZE;

  // Init SHA-1
  status = SHA1_Init(&SHA1ctx_st);
  if (status == HASH_SUCCESS)
  {
    // Process the message with SHA-1
    status = SHA1_Append(&SHA1ctx_st, (const uint8_t *)Message, MessageSize);
    if (status == HASH_SUCCESS)
    {
      // Output the Digest
      status = SHA1_Finish(&SHA1ctx_st, Digest, &outputSize);
      if (status == HASH_SUCCESS)
      {
        // It's OK, but result in Digest isn't correct
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I missing? Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: What result *do* you get? Just found [this](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkamTSAR/sha1-problem-with-stm32-crypto-lib), maybe it is related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. 
ST has historically locked these libraries to the STM32 parts by probing the CRC peripheral, basically a challenge-response test.
To do, it is necessary to enable RCC_CRC_CLK. With CubeMX, you need to activate "CRC Mode and Configuration" in Computing Tab.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so it *had* to do something with the CRC config :) Hope my comment helped you on your way. Thanks for self-answering the question!